# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "append", cartItems is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, cart, shopping-cart

**How do I add items to cart page from menu page**?  *below is the code I wrote and I keep getting an error*  Also the new div i created is not working on the cart page as the add to cart button is on the menu page and am trying to get the items from the menu page to the cart page

````
    let addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-food-item')
    
    for (let i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        let button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    function addToCartClicked(event) {
        let button = event.target
        let cartFoodItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
        let title = cartFoodItem.getElementsByClassName('cart-title')[0].innerText
        let cartPrice = cartFoodItem.getElementsByClassName('cart-food-price')[0].innerText
        let imageSrc = cartFoodItem.getElementsByClassName('cart-image')[0].src
        addItemToCart(title, cartPrice, imageSrc)
    }

    function addItemToCart(title, cartPrice, imageSrc) {
        let cartRow = document.createElement('div')
        cartRow.innerText = title
        let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-Items')[0]
        let cartRowContents =`
        <div class="col-5 cart-item cart-column d-flex">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="assets/images/food25.jpeg">
            <span class="cart-item-title">PORK SANDWICH</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 cart-price cart-column">
            <span>$40.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 cart-quantity cart-column d-flex">
            <input type="number" value="1" class=" mr-sm-3 cart-quantity-input">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
        cartItems.append(cartRow)
    }```
````

Comment: If `cartItems` is `undefined` then there are no elements with class `cart-Items` in the DOM when `addItemToCart()` is executed.

Comment: It's possible you misspelled the `cart-Items` class and it's actually `cart-items` instead. Also use `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName` if you're only looking for the first element with the `.cart-Items` class.